# Disable a video in CSS

Tags: html, css, html5-video, browser-extension

I'm writing a browser extension that removes distractions from a page by injecting CSS, mostly in the form of `display: none !important` rules.

However, this site auto-plays video on loading, and I'm realizing that my usual CSS techniques don't work to keep that video from playing out loud; `display: none;` might effectively remove the element from interacting with the DOM, but that doesn't mean it's been destroyed or stopped.

Is there any way to stop or mute `<video>` elements using CSS, or should I look for a JavaScript solution?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to disable using css. You can do it in javascript like this.

```
const vids = document.querySelectorAll('video');
vids.forEach( x => x.removeAttribute('autoplay'));
```